# Rendering part of component outside of the component itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-components

I have JSFiddle like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ownvjjow/

Basically the problem is that I'd like to render some part of component `x` outside of the element(`x`) itself. Like in the outer scope, but with preserving the scope of it in other component(`y`). I have part of the component that may be wanted to be rendered with `targetElement` set, but it seems like `ng-repeat` have some problem with it. The fiddle returns some other error, the one I get in my app is:
[image]
I could propably break the part that I want to be "moving" as another component then conditionally render it in other place providing the `bindings: {... , controller: '<'}` then expose the scope from component `x` to the `x.y` but I was wondering if there is an option to compile this part of component `x` and inject it in other place with everything working correctly.

I am not sure if my approach is right or maybe I should think about something different, if you know any other solution/idea then I would be grateful if you let me know about it.

Comment: If you have the same origin of data... the outside component could generate their data independently from the first component. Try to isolate that component.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, I know that components should be isolated from each other, but I have the need to show part of component in a place that is outside of it(in the element specified in `targetElement`). I am not particularly sure if this is the best way to achieve this, but I don't see other ways to do it and stay flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3koo4kvf/)

```
if(this.options.targetElement) {
  var parentElem = angular.element((this.options.targetElement));
  var childElem = $compile(this.container)($scope)[0];
  $timeout( function(){
        parentElem.append(childElem);
  }, 0, false );
  }
```

This will give AngularJS time to finish its compile.

Hope this help.

Comment: Cool, totally forgot that the `$compile` is asynchrounous. Perfect answer, thanks !